# MySQL plugin for Qt 5.1, Android

Tags: android, mysql, qt

I'm using Qt 5.1.1 and trying to launch existing application on Android. Things goes well but there is a part in that app that communicqtes with MySQL database. Unfortunately default qt package has no prebuilt mysql plugin. So my question is: are there any resources where I can get prebuilt mysql plugin for Qt 5.1 Android?

Thanks.

Comment: Check out this official guide for building Qt MySQL for Android: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Build_Qt5_mysql_plugin_for_Android

As I have learned, MySQL binaries depend heavily on your Qt version so it is hard to find compatible binaries. For example, 5.0.2 may not be compatible with 5.1.1.

Comment: @vkjr Have you found a binary version or you built yours?

Comment: @Baso, from what I remember, I found precompiled version here - https://github.com/0x-ff/libmysql-android There is also a good explanation of build process.. but in Russian :)